# IDbAsyncQueryProvider in EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-core

I'm using XUNIT to test in a dot net core application.

I need to test a service that is internally making an async query on a DbSet in my datacontext.

[I've seen here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429#async) that mocking that DbSet asynchronously is possible.

The problem I'm having is that the `IDbAsyncQueryProvider` does not seem to be available in EntityframeworkCore, which I'm using.

Am I incorrect here? Has anyone else got this working?

(Been a long day, hopefully I'm just missing something simple)

**EDIT**

After asking on GitHub, I got point to this class:
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/Query/Internal/IAsyncQueryProvider.cs

This is what I've gotten to so far in trying to implement this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal;

namespace EFCoreTestQueryProvider
{
    internal class TestAsyncQueryProvider<TEntity>: IAsyncQueryProvider
    {
        private readonly IQueryProvider _inner;

        internal TestAsyncQueryProvider(IQueryProvider inner)
        {
            _inner = inner;
        }

        IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
        {
            return new TestDbAsyncEnumerable<TEntity>(expression);
        }

        IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
        {
             return new TestDbAsyncEnumerable<TElement>(expression);
        }

        object Execute(Expression expression)
        {
            return _inner.Execute(expression);
        }

        TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
        {
            return _inner.Execute<TResult>(expression);
        }

        IAsyncEnumerable<TResult> ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression expression)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(Execute<TResult>(expression)).ToAsyncEnumerable();
        }

        Task<TResult> IAsyncQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(Execute<TResult>(expression));
        }
    }

    internal class TestDbAsyncEnumerable<T> : EnumerableQuery<T>, System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable<T>, IQueryable<T>
    {
        public TestDbAsyncEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
            : base(enumerable)
        { }

        public TestDbAsyncEnumerable(Expression expression)
            : base(expression)
        { }

        public IAsyncEnumerator<T> GetAsyncEnumerator()
        {
            return new TestDbAsyncEnumerable<T>(this.AsEnumerable()).ToAsyncEnumerable();
        }

        IDbAsyncEnumerator IDbAsyncEnumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator()
        {
            return GetAsyncEnumerator();
        }

        IAsyncEnumerator<T> IAsyncEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        IQueryProvider IQueryable.Provider
        {
            get { return new TestAsyncQueryProvider<T>(this); }
        }
    }
}
```

I've now tried to implement this and have run into some more issues, specifically around these two methods:

```
public IAsyncEnumerator<T> GetAsyncEnumerator()
{
    return new TestDbAsyncEnumerable<T>(this.AsEnumerable()).ToAsyncEnumerable();
}

IDbAsyncEnumerator IDbAsyncEnumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator()
{
    return GetAsyncEnumerator();
}
```

I'm hoping that somebody could point me in the right direction as to what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What new issues have you run into? Should add the new issues to the question (and title).

Comment: Did you find the solution to this?

Comment: @Dan I ended up moving on without a solution.

Answer (score 28):

I finally got this to work. They slightly changed the interfaces in EntityFrameworkCore from `IDbAsyncEnumerable` to `IAsyncEnumerable` so the following code worked for me:

```
public class AsyncEnumerable<T> : EnumerableQuery<T>, IAsyncEnumerable<T>, IQueryable<T>
{
    public AsyncEnumerable(Expression expression)
        : base(expression) { }

    public IAsyncEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() =>
        new AsyncEnumerator<T>(this.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator());
}

public class AsyncEnumerator<T> : IAsyncEnumerator<T>
{
    private readonly IEnumerator<T> enumerator;

    public AsyncEnumerator(IEnumerator<T> enumerator) =>
        this.enumerator = enumerator ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();

    public T Current => enumerator.Current;

    public void Dispose() { }

    public Task<bool> MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
        Task.FromResult(enumerator.MoveNext());
}

[Fact]
public async Task TestEFCore()
{
    var data =
        new List<Entity>()
        {
            new Entity(),
            new Entity(),
            new Entity()
        }.AsQueryable();

    var mockDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<Entity>>();

    mockDbSet.As<IAsyncEnumerable<Entity>>()
        .Setup(d => d.GetEnumerator())
        .Returns(new AsyncEnumerator<Entity>(data.GetEnumerator()));

    mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<Entity>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
    mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<Entity>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
    mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<Entity>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
    mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<Entity>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

    var mockCtx = new Mock<SomeDbContext>();
    mockCtx.SetupGet(c => c.Entities).Returns(mockDbSet.Object);

    var entities = await mockCtx.Object.Entities.ToListAsync();

    Assert.NotNull(entities);
    Assert.Equal(3, entities.Count());
}
```

You might be able to clean up those test implementations of the `AsyncEnumerable` and `AsyncEnumerator` even more. I didn't try, I just got it to work.

Remember your `DbSet` on your `DbContext` needs to be marked as `virtual` or else you will need to implement some interface wrapper over the `DbContext` to make this work properly.

Comment: In addition to the code above setup the provider to be the `TestAsyncQueryProvider` as well:

`mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<TEnt>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(new TestAsyncQueryProvider<TEnt>(data.Provider));`

Comment: @Carson This fixed my issue too. Thanks!

Comment: Hi , Can I know how you solved this using ef6?

Answer (score 2):

I got help from [Carsons answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43594599/7131954), but I had to alter his code a bit to make it work with EntityFramework Core 6.4.4 and Moq.

Here is the altered code:

```
internal class AsyncEnumerable<T> : EnumerableQuery<T>, IAsyncEnumerable<T>, IQueryable<T>
{
    public AsyncEnumerable(Expression expression)
        : base(expression) { }

    public IAsyncEnumerator<T> GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) =>
        new AsyncEnumerator<T>(this.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator());
}

internal class AsyncEnumerator<T> : IAsyncEnumerator<T>, IAsyncDisposable, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IEnumerator<T> enumerator;

    private Utf8JsonWriter? _jsonWriter = new(new MemoryStream());

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(disposing: true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        await DisposeAsyncCore().ConfigureAwait(false);

        Dispose(disposing: false);
        #pragma warning disable CA1816 // Dispose methods should call SuppressFinalize

        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        #pragma warning restore CA1816 // Dispose methods should call SuppressFinalize
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            _jsonWriter?.Dispose();
            _jsonWriter = null;
        }
    }

    protected virtual async ValueTask DisposeAsyncCore()
    {
        if (_jsonWriter is not null)
        {
            await _jsonWriter.DisposeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        _jsonWriter = null;
    }

    public AsyncEnumerator(IEnumerator<T> enumerator) =>
        this.enumerator = enumerator ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();

    public T Current => enumerator.Current;

    public ValueTask<bool> MoveNextAsync() =>
        new ValueTask<bool>(enumerator.MoveNext());
}

internal class TestAsyncQueryProvider<TEntity> : IDbAsyncQueryProvider
{
    private readonly IQueryProvider _inner;

    internal TestAsyncQueryProvider(IQueryProvider inner)
    {
        _inner = inner;
    }

    public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
    {
        return new AsyncEnumerable<TEntity>(expression);
    }

    public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
    {
        return new AsyncEnumerable<TElement>(expression);
    }

    public object Execute(Expression expression)
    {
        return _inner.Execute(expression);
    }

    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
    {
        return _inner.Execute<TResult>(expression);
    }

    public Task<object> ExecuteAsync(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(Execute(expression));
    }

    public Task<TResult> ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(Execute<TResult>(expression));
    }
}
```

A helper class:

```
public static class MockDbSet
{       
    public static Mock<DbSet<TEntity>> BuildAsync<TEntity>(List<TEntity> data) where TEntity : class
    {
        var queryable = data.AsQueryable();

        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<TEntity>>();
        mockSet.As<IAsyncEnumerable<TEntity>>()
            .Setup(d => d.GetAsyncEnumerator(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
            .Returns(new AsyncEnumerator<TEntity>(queryable.GetEnumerator()));

        mockSet.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>()
            .Setup(m => m.Provider)
            .Returns(new TestAsyncQueryProvider<TEntity>(queryable.Provider));

        mockSet.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(queryable.Expression);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(queryable.ElementType);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => queryable.GetEnumerator());

        mockSet.Setup(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<TEntity>())).Callback<TEntity>(data.Add);
        return mockSet;
    }
}
```

Mocking async unit test (MSTestV2):

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task GetData_Should_Not_Return_Null()
    {
        // Arrange
        var data = new List<Entity>()
        {
            new Entity()
        };

        _mockContext.Setup(m => m.Entitys).Returns(MockDbSet.BuildAsync(data).Object);

        // Act 
        var actual = await _repository.GetDataAsync();

        // Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See here to mock DbContext with async queryable support: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71076807/4905704

Like this:

```cs
    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        var testData = new List<MyEntity>
        {
            new MyEntity() { Id = Guid.NewGuid() },
            new MyEntity() { Id = Guid.NewGuid() },
            new MyEntity() { Id = Guid.NewGuid() },
        };

        var mockDbContext = new MockDbContextAsynced<MyDbContext>();
        mockDbContext.AddDbSetData<MyEntity>(testData.AsQueryable());

        mockDbContext.MyEntities.ToArrayAsync();
        // or
        mockDbContext.MyEntities.SingleAsync();
        // or etc.
        
        // To inject MyDbContext as type parameter with mocked data
        var mockService = new SomeService(mockDbContext.Object);
    }
```