# Moq async DbSet Setup IDbAsyncQueryProvider

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I have this Moq setup:

```
_mockContext.Setup(x => x.CarSections).Returns(new List<CarSection> { _carSection }.ToDbSet());
```

Which basically assigns the List to the entity of DbContext.CarSections.

One of the methods is an async method. Something like:

```
public async Task<CarSection> GetSectionAsync(int sectionId)
    {
        return await _context
            .CarSections
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.CarSectionId == sectionId && s.StatusCode == 4);
    }
```

When it goes through that method I'm getting the error:

> The provider for the source `IQueryable` doesn't implement
>   `IDbAsyncQueryProvider`. Only providers that implement
>   `IDbAsyncQueryProvider` can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous
>   operations.

Which I believe is because of the .ToDbSet(). Already tried with `Task.FromResult(new List<CarSection>{ _carSection }` but the .Returns expects a "DbSet" and not a "Task".

Any ideas on how to workaround this?

Comment: No clue where ToDbSet is from, but assuming it's setting up a Mock, you'd need to add mock.As<IDbAsyncQueryProvider>() followed by setup of the methods on that interface. Perhaps this answer to this question helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/43594599/491907

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that the `.ToDbSet()` extension (what package is this extension from?) doesn't setup the `IQueryable<T>.Provider` property with a provider that implements `IDbAsyncQueryProvider`.

How would I resolve this?

- Look for a mocking library that will do this for you. I moved to EFCore a fair while ago and so I am not sure what the landscape currently looks like for EF, possibly [Effort](https://entityframework-effort.net/)?
- If you want to roll your own check out the [doco from MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/mocking#testing-with-async-queries) which provides a ready to go copy/paste Moq implementation. There's a bit of scaffolding involved but MS has done the hard work for you. You'll end up creating your own implementation of `IDbAsyncQueryProvider` and using that as the provider for your `DbSet<T>`.

Comment: This what I ended up doing at the end. Works perfectly, thanks.

Comment: Hi , Can I know how you solve this question? @rmed1na

Comment: @JiriumJ sure, I ended doing the thing on the second bullet point of this answer. Just copy/paste the implementation MS provides on their website. So far, has been working fine with no need to tweak anything since then.