# C# unit test mocking DbSet errors with IQueryable not implementing IAsyncEnumerable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mocking

I have the test below and am using standard mocking on a DbSet/Context.  When the test runs it fails as it states that "The source IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncEnumerable Team.  Only sources that implement IAsyncEnumerable can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations".

```
        public async Task Get_team_name_with_valid_search_term_returns_team_names()
        {
            // Arrange
            var data = new List<Team>
            {
                new Team {Name = "Leeds"},
                new Team {Name = "Glasgow"}
            }.AsQueryable();

            var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Team>>();

            mockSet.As<IQueryable<Team>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<Team>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<Team>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<Team>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

            var mockContext = new Mock<RadContext>();
            mockContext.Setup(c => c.Team).Returns(mockSet.Object);

            var service = new ITeamSearchService(mockContext.Object);

            // Act
            var result = await service.GetTeamName("Gla");

            // Assert
        }
```

The service itself is quite simple

```
 public async Task<List<SearchTeamResponse>> GetTeamName(string searchTerm)
      {
            if (searchTerm == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(searchTerm));
            }

            var query = await _radContext.Team.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(searchTerm))
                .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
                .ToListAsync();

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query);

            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SearchTeamResponse>>(json);

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: I ran into this issue some time ago when looking at fully embracing `IQueryable` in my repository and some of the challenges faced when testing async operations.  The solution was outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41324783/unit-testing-tolistasync-using-an-in-memory/41327224  Basically adding the test provider and enumerator, then where you want to return a stub IQueryable result, return a `TestDbAsyncEnumerable<T>` wrapped collection.

Comment: @StevePy - thanks for the article, unfortunately IDbAsyncQueryProvider is no longer recognised in entity framework core as i think they have changed the interfaces.

Comment: A quick search revealed this for the alternative in EF Core: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39719258/idbasyncqueryprovider-in-entityframeworkcore  EF Core is always in a bit of flux but it should have an alternative wrapper for accommodating async.